# Forwarding DNS to Cloudflare's DNS-over-TLS via CoreDNS

Tags: dns, coredns

I'm [using this Docker image](https://github.com/ivanrad/docker-coredns-cloudflare) as an example to try to setup secure DNS forwarding over TLS to CloudFlare's resolvers. I'm using CoreDNS 1.5.0 (latest) and my config is this:

```
# CoreDNS Configuration

.:53 {
  forward . tls://1.1.1.1 tls://1.0.0.1 {
    tls_servername tls.cloudflare-dns.com
    policy sequential
    health_check 5s
  }

  log
}
```

I'm making requests like so:

```
root@8ef125545369:/# dig @127.0.0.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 49802
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 090b0d7fadcdd8bb (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 08 19:29:30 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

I'm not getting answers. The CoreDNS logs look like this:

```
missioncontrol    | 2019-04-08T19:29:30.778Z [INFO] 127.0.0.1:39615 - 49802 "A IN google.com. udp 51 false 4096" NOERROR - 0 5.02365452s
missioncontrol    | 2019-04-08T19:29:35.759Z [INFO] 127.0.0.1:39615 - 49802 "A IN google.com. udp 51 false 4096" NOERROR - 0 5.00549558s
```

It's clear that CoreDNS is getting the requests, but I can't determine why this is failing. My image is `ubuntu:bionic` and `ca-certificates` is installed. I can also use `openssl s_client` to connect to `1.1.1.1:443` without issues.

Is there something I'm missing to setup DNS-over-TLS forwarding from CoreDNS to CloudFlare's resolvers?

---

#### EDIT

I've tested this on my host operating system outside of a Docker container and I'm seeing the same functionality, namely that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this again by running it in Travis CI, and it worked; apparently my corporate firewall does not like DNS-over-TLS.

I was able to validate this by installing `knot-dnsutils` (on Ubuntu 18.04) and trying to query Cloudflare directly:

```
$ kdig -d @1.0.0.1 +tls-ca +tls-host=cloudflare-dns.com google.com
;; DEBUG: Querying for owner(google.com.), class(1), type(1), server(1.0.0.1), port(853), protocol(TCP)
;; DEBUG: TLS, imported 133 system certificates
;; DEBUG: TLS, received certificate hierarchy:
;; DEBUG:  #1, C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=Cloudflare\, Inc.,CN=cloudflare-dns.com
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: V6zes8hHBVwUECsHf7uV5xGM7dj3uMXIS9//7qC8+jU=
;; DEBUG:  #2, C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert ECC Secure Server CA
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: PZXN3lRAy+8tBKk2Ox6F7jIlnzr2Yzmwqc3JnyfXoCw=
;; DEBUG: TLS, skipping certificate PIN check
;; DEBUG: TLS, The certificate is trusted.
;; WARNING: TLS, handshake failed (Error in the pull function.)
```

This is what happened when querying within the corporate network. From Travis CI, I saw:

```
;; DEBUG: Querying for owner(google.com.), class(1), type(1), server(1.1.1.1), port(853), protocol(TCP)
;; DEBUG: TLS, imported 133 system certificates
;; DEBUG: TLS, received certificate hierarchy:
;; DEBUG:  #1, C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=Cloudflare\, Inc.,CN=cloudflare-dns.com
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: V6zes8hHBVwUECsHf7uV5xGM7dj3uMXIS9//7qC8+jU=
;; DEBUG:  #2, C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert ECC Secure Server CA
;; DEBUG:      SHA-256 PIN: PZXN3lRAy+8tBKk2Ox6F7jIlnzr2Yzmwqc3JnyfXoCw=
;; DEBUG: TLS, skipping certificate PIN check
;; DEBUG: TLS, The certificate is trusted. 
;; TLS session (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-ECDSA-SECP256R1)-(AES-256-GCM)
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY; status: NOERROR; id: 59442
;; Flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1; ANSWER: 1; AUTHORITY: 0; ADDITIONAL: 1
;; EDNS PSEUDOSECTION:
;; Version: 0; flags: ; UDP size: 1452 B; ext-rcode: NOERROR
;; PADDING: 69 B
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;; google.com.              IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             156 IN  A   172.217.5.14
;; Received 128 B
;; Time 2019-04-09 22:03:18 UTC
;; From 1.1.1.1@853(TCP) in 12.8 ms
```

Clearly the corporate firewall is blocking this access unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `security.cloudflare-dns.com` instead of `tls.cloudflare-dns.com` and `1.1.1.2` - `1.0.0.2` instead of `1.1.1.1` - `1.0.0.1` in your Corefile, works for me.

Maybe the problem lies with the fact that ip's of `tls.cloudflare-dns.com` are not `1.1.1.1` - `1.0.0.1`.

If you want to use `1.1.1.1` - `1.0.0.1`, use the domain from cloudflare that actually uses those ip's: `one.one.one.one`. You can verify this by using the `dig` command `dig domain_to_lookup`.

Example:

```
# CoreDNS Configuration

.:53 {
  forward . tls://1.1.1.2 tls://1.0.0.2 {
    tls_servername security.cloudflare-dns.com
    policy sequential
    health_check 5s
  }

  log
}
```

Also you might need to disable `systemd-resolved`.

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

And then enable coredns

```
sudo systemctl enable coredns
sudo systemctl start coredns
sudo systemctl status coredns
```